# GXT (EXT-GWT) Project compilation failed - Default Setup

Tags: gwt, gxt

***I have set up GXT by following default instructions. When i run the project in Eclipse, everything displays nice in development mode. On the other hand when i try to compile the project it gives me this error:***

Compiling module com.gxt.Gxt
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/sdks/gxt-2.2.1/gxt.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/data/BeanModelLookup.java'
      [ERROR]  Internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.BeanModelGenerator.isBeanMarker(BeanModelGenerator.java:197)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.BeanModelGenerator.generate(BeanModelGenerator.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:517)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:541)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:495)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:407)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)

[ERROR] Unexpected
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.BeanModelGenerator.isBeanMarker(BeanModelGenerator.java:197)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.BeanModelGenerator.generate(BeanModelGenerator.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:517)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:541)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:495)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:407)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)

***Any help would be very appreciated.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself. There is an incompatibility between the latest GWT 2.2.0 SDK and the standard EXT-GWT version 2.2.1. I switched back the GWT version to the previous release 2.0.4 and everything works fine. I hope EXT-GWT will soon update it's SDK to catch up with GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure adding the gxt2.2.4-gwt22.jar in the download folder. I've lost 3 hours ><

Answer (score 1):

This is simple versioning problem make sure to install same version which is compatible